# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'annotate_video'

Tags: python, jupyter-lab, google-vision, video-intelligence-api

Using the following code on JupyterLab in order to run Google Video Intelligence Package:

```
from google.cloud import videointelligence
import os

client = videointelligence.VideoIntelligenceServiceClient('VidIntelligence.JSON')
job = client.annotate_video(
    input_uri='gs://vidintelligencebucket/The Simpsons - Monopoly Night.mp4',
    features=['LABEL_DETECTION', 'SHOT_CHANGE_DETECTION'],
)
result = job.result()
```

When I run it, the following error appears:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'annotate_video'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try to print that `client` variable. Would there be some error message waiting for you. That code is basicly copy&paste from example, so it should work.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because as [ex4](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2740928/ex4) pointed out variable `client` is of type `str` and just contains an error message.

The error occurs because you are trying to authenticate in a non correct way. The argument passed to the `credentials` parameter of the client cannot be of type `str` but should be a [Credentials](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/google.auth.credentials.html#google.auth.credentials.Credentials) object as stated in the `client` [description](https://googleapis.dev/python/videointelligence/latest/gapic/v1/api.html).

You can check this [overview](https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/auth.html#overview) for all the valid ways to authenticate the client.

Since you have a `json` file with the credentials you just need to point to it using an environment variable named `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`:

```
$ export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/path/to/VidIntelligence.json"
```

Then you will be able to initialize your client without passing any arguments:

```
client = videointelligence.VideoIntelligenceServiceClient()
```

Hope that this helps!